# Auto suspend VMs when closing vmware window

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

When I'm closing the vmware workstation's main window, this dialog pops up:

[image]

How do I get rid of it? Is there a way to automatically suspend all running VMs without confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get rid of it? Is there a way to automatically suspend all
> running VMs without confirmation?

Natively, no. VMware does not know what you want. I run into this with VMware here all the time.

If you suspend the host machine, then the VMs will suspend (newest version of VMware). I use this function.

If you turn off the host machine with shutdown /s, VMware will also suspend the guest machines.

If you use regular shutdown and if it is too fast, the guest machines will just force off and that is not good for any machine.